# C16 Wood Strength

Tags: wood, load

I'm looking to hang some kids bicycles up inside my car barn. I have a 2021 new build house in the UK, and a wooden car barn.

If I were to buy a 3.3 meter length of C16, available at various widths (45x120mm, 45x170mm, etc) and hang this using coach screws at each end inside the car barn, how much weight could it hold in the middle?

I wouldn't want the C16 to just snap.. or cause issues with the car barn. I know it's tricky without knowing exactly how the car barn is engineered, but is this a good idea generally or a stupid one, would the weight of kids bikes (5) be too much for it to hold? Or I could skip the C16 and just screw the hooks into the beams inside the car barn and hang them from that, but I'd prefer not to mess with the car barn beams too much if I can avoid it.

Comment: The [Sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) is a great source for determining how much flex there will be in a shelf. You're basically building a shallow (45mm) shelf with a thick (120mm) board and your load is going under instead of on top. I'm sure you can use the Sagulator to calculate how much flex there will be with the span between support bolts and the amount of weight you expect to hang from it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information at [this site](https://www.hitchcockandking.co.uk/h-k-news/c16-or-c24-timber-for-your-construction-project/) (the first site I found in a search for "c16 wood", no affiliation, never heard of them before - they seem to be a UK retailer):

> C16 graded timber allows for a number of defects that may reduce the overall strength of the wood, such as grain deviations and wanes, as well as an unlimited amount of superficial defects that do not affect the strength of the wood, such as blue sap stains and the like. **C16 is the most widely used timber in the UK** as it is strong enough to be used in most applications and is the most cost effective timber option.
> <sup>Emphasis theirs</sup>

It sounds like C16 is exactly what your car shed was built out of in the first place, therefore, the use of C16 for future projects seems to be entirely reasonable.

It seems your other option is C24, about which the same site says:

> **C24 boards have fewer defects than C16** graded timber and the timber is therefore stronger and more resilient than C16 boards. You will also find that C24 boards have a more uniformed and neat appearance as there are fewer physical imperfections on the surface of the board. C24s are not as widely used as C16 as the timber is much more expensive because the demand for high standard boards means that there are a lot of boards rejected, so you gain less timber from the same amount of wood as you would C16 boards. **Generally, C24 boards have to be imported too, which can drive the price up.**
> <sup>Emphasis theirs</sup>

So you could go ahead with an upgrade to C24, but it will cost you more and it sounds to me like it would be unnecessary.

---

#### To specifically address your question:

If I were to do this, I'd lag/carriage/coach bolt a 2x4"<sup>*</sup> (37x87mm) across several rafters, putting one 1/4" or 3/8" (6 or 10mm) bolt through each junction. I'd lay the board flat (smaller dimension vertical) then screw the bike hooks in between the joists/rafters. I'd lay it flat because that would be easier to attach and for the reasonably light weight of a kids bike, should be sufficiently strong to hold it without significant sag. Attaching it with the 4" dimension vertically would increase the strength, but that also increases the length of bolts necessary for attaching and makes it more critical that your pilot holes be accurate to ensure they don't miss the joists above.

However, I'd *only* do this if screwing the bike hooks *directly* into the joists/rafters would put the bikes in an awkward position where they'd interfere with walking or parking a car below.

For example, I've got my old road bike (college era, was wrecked heavily, keeping it for sentimental reasons), hanging from the *side* of a roof truss by 2 hooks, one for each wheel. It's a lighter frame, for racing, but as a full-size frame, it's probably fairly comparable in weight to a smaller kid's bike. The trusses were manufactured from the aforementioned 2x4" and I simply drilled a pilot hole then screwed the hooks in to the 4" dimension side.

At one point, I'd also placed hooks into the vertical studs in the garage wall to hold up full-sized adult mountain bikes, hanging by the front wheel (disclosure: the rear wheels was on the ground, so the hook wasn't supporting the full weight - this was just for convenience of getting the bike on the hook so we didn't have to lift them, I'd have been 100% comfortable with the full weight supported by the hook). These went into the 2" dimension, again predrilled and screwed directly in. There is no concern whatsoever about damaging either the studs or joists with such a small hole. Just be certain to get your hole straight into the joist above so that you don't accidentally angle out the side - it weakens the connection for the hangar itself (either bike hook directly or a bolt) and *could* weaken the joist.

<sup>*</sup>Note that in the US, lumber is sold in a *nominal* dimension of 2x4", while the *actual* dimension is 1-1/2" x 3-1/2". I converted the *actual* dimension to mm for you, since I believe in the UK/Europe, lumber is sold by the *actual* dimension. Feel free to use whatever dimension is close to a US (nominal) 2x4" and is available near you.